# How to create blob stream using unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, blob, c++builder

When using the following code I am successfully saving the image into "Image" blob field:

```
if (OpenDialog1->Execute()) {
    ADOTable1->Insert();
    TStream* BlobStream = ADOTable1->CreateBlobStream(ADOTable1->FieldByName("Image"), bmWrite);
    std::unique_ptr<TFileStream> FileStream(new TFileStream(OpenDialog1->FileName, fmOpenRead));
    BlobStream->CopyFrom(FileStream.get(), FileStream->Size);
    delete BlobStream;
    ADOTable1->Post();
}
```

But, I would like to have `BlobStream` object to be created using `std:unique_ptr` as well so I could avoid manual `delete`. When I try

```
if (OpenDialog1->Execute()) {
    ADOTable1->Insert();
    std::unique_ptr<TStream> BlobStream(ADOTable1->CreateBlobStream(ADOTable1->FieldByName("Image"), bmWrite));
    std::unique_ptr<TFileStream> FileStream(new TFileStream(OpenDialog1->FileName, fmOpenRead));
    BlobStream->CopyFrom(FileStream.get(), FileStream->Size);
    ADOTable1->Post();
}
```

i get **Empty row cannot be inserted** error. What am I doing wrong here? I'm using C++ Builder 10.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original code, you were `delete`'ing the blob `TStream` object **before** you called `Post()`.

Per the `TADOBlobStream` documentation:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOBlobStream.Destroy

> Destroy [ie, the destructor] performs the following tasks:
>
> - **Sets the field's data.**
> - Changes the field object's Modified property to true.
> - Triggers a field change event in the field's dataset object.
> - Calls the inherited destructor.

Thus, you were setting the blob's field data before `Post()`'ing it, and all was good.

In the updated code, you are `delete`'ing the blob `TStream` object when `BlobStream` goes out of scope **after** calling `Post()`.  Thus, the field data has not been set yet, hence the error.

To ensure the blob `TStream` object gets destructed before `Post()` is called, you can either:

- put a new scope around `BlobStream`:

```cpp
if (OpenDialog1->Execute()) {
    std::unique_ptr<TFileStream> FileStream(new TFileStream(OpenDialog1->FileName, fmOpenRead));
    ADOTable1->Insert();
    {
    std::unique_ptr<TStream> BlobStream(ADOTable1->CreateBlobStream(ADOTable1->FieldByName("Image"), bmWrite));
    BlobStream->CopyFrom(FileStream.get(), FileStream->Size);
    }
    ADOTable1->Post();
}
```

- call [`reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) on `BlobStream` manually:

```cpp
if (OpenDialog1->Execute()) {
    std::unique_ptr<TFileStream> FileStream(new TFileStream(OpenDialog1->FileName, fmOpenRead));
    ADOTable1->Insert();
    std::unique_ptr<TStream> BlobStream(ADOTable1->CreateBlobStream(ADOTable1->FieldByName("Image"), bmWrite));
    BlobStream->CopyFrom(FileStream.get(), FileStream->Size);
    BlobStream.reset();
    ADOTable1->Post();
}
```

Either way, you should put in some error handling to that you can [`Cancel()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Cancel) the new row insertion if something unexpected happens before it can be `Post()`'ed, eg:

```cpp
if (OpenDialog1->Execute()) {
    std::unique_ptr<TFileStream> FileStream(new TFileStream(OpenDialog1->FileName, fmOpenRead));
    ADOTable1->Insert();
    try {
        std::unique_ptr<TStream> BlobStream(ADOTable1->CreateBlobStream(ADOTable1->FieldByName("Image"), bmWrite));
        BlobStream->CopyFrom(FileStream.get(), FileStream->Size);
        BlobStream.reset();
        ADOTable1->Post();
    }
    catch (const Exception &) {
        ADOTable1->Cancel();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see the updated content and the statement that "Destroy" actually "sets the field's data". Now it makes sense why it was not working. Still, that is not somehow logical to me.

Comment: @Tracer Well, it is a stream, after all. You could write to it multiple times. It needs to know when you are done writing to it. If that were not handled by the destructor, an explicit method call would be needed instead, eg: `BlobStream = ...; BlobStream->Write(...); BlobStream->CommitModifiedData(); ADOTable1->Post(); delete BlobStream;` Once committed, the stream can't be used anymore. So the destructor makes more sense.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer some explicit method to set the value of the blob field. This is very specific and I have never seen someone use destructor in such manner and for anything else than 'cleaning' the object. I wish they would implement something as `ADOTable1->FieldByName("Image")->LoadFromStream(...)` or `AsStream` etc. that would be supported on blob/binary type of fields.

Comment: @Tracer "*I wish they would implement something as `ADOTable1->FieldByName("Image")->LoadFromStream(...)`*" - they did, actually. `TBlobField` has a public [`LoadFromStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TBlobField.LoadFromStream) method, eg: `static_cast<TBlobField*>(ADOTable1->FieldByName("Image"))->LoadFromStream(...);`

Comment: Excellent! Now this works too: `dynamic_cast<TBlobField*> (ADOTable1->FieldByName("Image"))->LoadFromStream(FileStream.get());`

Comment: @Tracer why did you change to `dynamic_cast`? You are not checking the result for null. `static_cast` is more appropriate

Comment: It was just a quick test. I was not sure if it was upcast or downcast. Of course, it works with `static_cast` too. But even better, there is a `LoadFromFile` method to make things even faster without the use of `TFileStream`. Simply `static_cast<TBlobField*> (ADOTable1->FieldByName("Image"))->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);`